# how to call the chart in excel using poi method?

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts

i have an excel template and there was a chart there, I was confuse on how can I call that chart when I'm coding in vb.net.. Can anyone help me on how can I call the chart for me to set the new value to fill the chart.. It is possible to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all the chart linked data range to Defined name range,then you only need to change the defined name range link source if you want to change the chart's data source.